# End of Statement expected in concatenating a message string

Tags: vb.net

Im new to programming and I cannot figure out why it says End of Statement Expected under `EventInteger.ToString()` I tried to copy the example in my VB book but it's not working.

```
MessageString = "Total Daily Sales:" &
        DailyTotalDecimal.ToString("C") &
        Environment.NewLine & Environment.Newline &
        "Total Number of Orders:" EventInteger.ToString()
```

Answer (score 3):

The line-continuation character in VB is `_`. Reference: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/141513

> To continue a statement from one line to the next, type a space
>   followed by the line-continuation character [the underscore character
>   on your keyboard (`_`)].

Example:

```
MessageString = "Total Daily Sales:" & _
        DailyTotalDecimal.ToString("C") & _
        Environment.NewLine & Environment.Newline & _
        "Total Number of Orders:" & EventInteger.ToString() 'you were missing a &
```

Comment: Oops! Just deleted my comment ;-) Sorry!

Comment: No need to apologise. Thanks for commenting

Comment: I finally figured out what you were pointing out. I needed the & before EventsInteger.ToSting(). What is sad is you put the correction on that line and I still missed it. BUT, I got it and everything works now Thanks!